# How can I identify a connector type?

Tags: connector

**How do I go about identifying an unknown connector, either from spec or measurement?**

For example, I've got a [GM4632-730 DC motor](https://uk.banggood.com/GM4632-370-DC-24V-80RPM-High-torque-Turbo-Encoder-Motor-Worm-Geared-Motor-Reducer-Motor-p-1069462.html), which unfortunately came without the cable (and to make things worse, the connector partially broken)

[image: Motor (connector)]

All that's obvious to me is number of pins (and number of rows), pitch, and 'shape'. The latter is tricky to describe or search for.

[Finding The JST Connector You Need (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wn3ixZ-sv5w%20led%20me%20to) gives a good understanding on relationship between pitch size and JST model numbers. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector) is even better, with links to relevant datasheets. While I measured the pitch at about 2.5mm, the shape doesn't seem to match any of the JST datasheets, and those I've got on hand don't quite fit.

Molex seems the next thing to try, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector) is not nearly so helpful covering only PC connectors. Where do I go next to work this out? What other common formats are there?

The Banggood.com page even includes a picture of the appropriate connector, and makes it clear it differs from those I've got here and have tried. Is there anything else I can do with this end?

[image: Cable connector]

*While this came about because I'm trying to find a specific connector and that remains my immediate issue, I'm more interested in how in general one can identify such connectors; short of holding stock of a variety and trying them all.*

Comment: the connector does not appear to be broken

Comment: "about 2.5mm". Is it 2.54 mm pitch, otherwise known as 0.1" (inch)? The connector in the picture isn't broken. It has a deliberate notch in one side to key it, preventing the matching connector from being inserted the wrong way round.

Comment: library picture, mine's definitely broken https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1yv7.jpg

Comment: It might take a serious effort to find the matching connector from regular distributor. If your cable is missing, the easy way is to search Banggood for "Machifit cable connector".

Comment: First, measure the pitch with better accuracy, take the distance between outer pins and divide by 5. Then go to DigiKey, and you might be lucky to match it by the shape of shroud.

Answer (score 1):

> how in general one can identify such connectors

Through this [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html).

Full disclosure: this is my website.